# How does optimizer minimizing with loss function work in deep reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function

I've been studying a block of code with simple and straightforward DQN implementation but I'm having trouble understanding a core process of the implementation.

By inserting batches of 64, they compute the current Q values for each sample, the current target Q value and they compute the final td-error. How can we train the neural network with just one single value? From my understanding of back-propagation, we need the complete values of our current and target network, and we need the loss function differences for each output value. Meaning if we have 4 actions (output neurons) we should have a total of 4x64 values to train our model with. How is it possible to train the model with just one single value, how does it know what to change if we provide no indication on which outputs where far off from the target?

They also just take the mean of all 64 errors and train the model accordingly, which just further reduces the information provided to the network on how to change its parameters accordingly.

What am I missing?

Code for reference:

```
td_error = q_t_selected - tf.stop_gradient(q_t_selected_target) # Q(s,a;θi) -  ( r + gamma * maxQ(s',a';θi-) )
errors = U.huber_loss(td_error)
weighted_error = tf.reduce_mean(importance_weights_ph * errors)
optimizer.minimize(weighted_error, var_list=q_func_vars)
```

Comment: Reinforcement learning is quite different from standard supervised learning, I would suggest you look into some conceptual guides on how (deep) Q learning etc work.

Comment: @xdurch0 they mostly skip this part or under-explain it. either they explain that "we backpropagate this value from the loss function to train normally the neural network", or that "we use this difference to train the network and expect little-by-little to move the values towards the correct action choice". they are not much of a help, and since most implementation already use fixed blocks of code, not many info can be found online on how specifically the network training works. any extra info is appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest watching a few videos/reading articles about gradient descent and neural network basics. How a DQN works with its loss function is really no special case of reinforcement learning. Basically, when doing a forward pass, the network saves all gradients with regard to that data, and the loss function is a target to minimize. You can take a look at [this article](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch), and especially the code part that starts with `epochs = 2`. There you can see that the optimizer gets the gradients, that were computed wrt the loss